# Самообучающийся фильтр спама

Tags: c#, алгоритм, фильтры, спам

Необходим самообучающийся фильтр спама для соц. сети. 
Интересуют как готовые реализации с открытым кодом, так и просто алгоритмы.

Буду рад полезным ссылкам по данной теме.

Comment: Определите, ЧТО есть спам, может быть как получать ОБРАЗЦЫ спама,
тогда можно говорить об алгоритмах.

Comment: Классический метод байеса, часто для электронной почты используется. Достаточно загуглить по "байесу" и "спаму"

Comment: Лучшее, что мне встречалось, - это Akismet.

Comment: @avp: фильтр спама нужен для автоматической фильтрации как личных сообщений пользователей, так и комментариев к статьям, новостям итд. 

Здесь я ориентировался на то, что было сделано в свое время вконтакте - пользователи сами помечают те, или иные сообщения/комментарии как спам.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на spam assasin. Это антиспам для почты, возможно с открытым кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [Dspam.](http://dspam.nuclearelephant.com/) Достаточно приличный проект с открытым исходным кодом.